# Create Action Can;t Save To Database -- Passing parameters from one form to another controller's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Right now I'm trying to build an app which has the ability to search for phone numbers, buy them, and record the transaction to a database.

The way I thought to do it was to have two controllers-- (1) the find_numbers controller takes paramaters and searches for numbers. And (2) the phones controller buys the chosen number and saves the parameters to the database.

Here's a diagram of what I'm trying to do.

http://www.stepanp.com/search-and-buy.jpg

Though I can search for the numbers, and buy the numbers, I can't seem to save it to the database.

**It redirects me and tells me that I did not fill in the proper fields.**

This makes me think that the parameters in find_numbers form aren't being accepted as the parameters for the create action of the phones controller

here's find_numbers/show

```
    <%= @numbers.each do |number| %>

        <%= form_tag(:controller => "phones", :action => "create" ) do %>
            <%= hidden_field :original_number, params[:original_number] %>
            <%= hidden_field :name, params[:name] %>
            <%= hidden_field(:twilio_number,  number.phone_number) %>

            <div class="found_list">
                <div class="found_phone_number">
                    <%= label_tag(:number, number.friendly_name) %>
                </div>
                <div class="choose_found_number">
                 <%= submit_tag("Choose This Number", :class => "btn btn-large btn-success") %>
                </div>
            </div>
                <hr>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

**And, here's the create action of the phones controller**

```
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @phone = @user.phones.build(params[:phone])
    client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@user.twilio_account_sid, @user.twilio_auth_token)
    number = client.account.incoming_phone_numbers.create(
                   :phone_number => params[:twilio_number])
    if @phone.save && !number.nil?
      flash[:success] = "Phone Number Created!"
      redirect_to user_path
    else
      render new_find_number_path
      flash[:error] = "It looks like there were errors with the submission"
    end
  end
```

What would I need to edit on the create action, to make it so it takes the parameters that the show action POSTS to it, and than saves it to the database?

I think this might be the culprit :

```
@phone = @user.phones.build(params[:phone])
```

Thanks for sticking with me this far! Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Here's the debugger information when I hit Phones#create via find_numbers/show

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
utf8: ✓
authenticity_token: RMvjP9PQt9hVEJE449pMqgqnFcreqvXtmZFEyU+641g=
original_number: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  '1231231234': ''
name: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  Example Name: ''
twilio_number: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  '+18322415354': ''
commit: Choose This Number
action: create
controller: phones
```

The Phone Model

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: phones
#
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  name            :string(255)
#  twilio_number   :string(255)
#  original_number :string(255)
#  user_id         :integer
#  created_at      :datetime         not null
#  updated_at      :datetime         not null
#

class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name, :original_number, :twilio_number
      belongs_to :user

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :twilio_number, presence: true
  validates :original_number, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  default_scope order: 'phones.created_at DESC'

end
```

http://stepanp.com/search-and-buy-debug.jpg

Comment: from where is params[:phone] no is passed

Comment: Hi Amar, thanks for your reply. Yeah, I'm not quite sure what to write there. The parameters for the phone are stored via the form on find_numbers/show (shown above), but I'm not sure how to tell the create action to use the parameters from that form

Comment: but you are passing original_number, twilio_number,...etc put debugger or pry in controller and check params hash

Comment: Just added the debug info on the post. It seems like it's passing the parameters over to it, though it redirected me and highlighted the field for name, as though it did not know the info for that. What do you think is happening?

Comment: what are the fields in phone model

Comment: Just updated that as well, alongside the command prompt info

Comment: not command prompt info what are database field in phone model,and validation in phone model if any

Comment: Hi Amar, put that in as well, it's above the command prompt image. Let me make a quick edit, to make it more prominent

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17560/discussion-between-amar-and-stepan-parunashvili)

Comment: Sorry for being late(Power went out in the apartment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
def create
    @user = current_user
    @phone = @user.phones.new(params[:phone])
    client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@user.twilio_account_sid, @user.twilio_auth_token)
    number = client.account.incoming_phone_numbers.create(
                   :phone_number => params[:twilio_number])
    if @phone.save && number.present?
      flash[:success] = "Phone Number Created!"
      redirect_to user_path
    else
      render new_find_number_path
      flash[:error] = "It looks like there were errors with the submission"
    end
end
```

Comment: Amar, thank you so much for your guidance! I tried changing the form to form_for, instead of form_tag, and set the @phone = @user.phones.new(params[:phone]) in the create action of the first controller. That way, it seemed to have worked.